# My objects in storyboard don't link correctly with the code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, hyperlink, storyboard, iboutlet

I am trying to use storyboards in my application. I began well, I have added two view controllers with a button to go from the first to the second. 
The problem is in this second view controller: the objects I add on it and link with the code do not work. When I set a breakpoint in the view controller code, the 'self.property' is set to nil, whereas it should be instantiated by the storyboard.

I have been looking for an answer for hours, and I really don't understand the problem, since all the rest seems to be good.

I have tried to write the property in the code (strong/nonatomic, nonatomic/retain and even weak/nonatomic), to link the object directly to the code so that it creates the property automatically, but I never get anything else than "nil" with breakpoints.

viewController.h:

```
@interface NMLoadingViewController : UIViewController
{
    __weak IBOutlet UIProgressView *imageProcessingProgressView;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *imageProcessingProgressView;

@end
```

.m:

```
@synthesize imageProcessingProgressView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // Custom initialization
    NSLog(@"INIT.");
}
```

(amont other lines of irrelevant code)

If I set the breakpoint to the "INIT." line, my imageProcessingProgressView is nil. I can't see a reason for that, I guess I have missed a very little detail...

(Note that I have tried this with other objects, like a UILabel, but it did not work either. Stranger, when I had two objects, one of them had an adress which was not nil, but still it was corrupted and did not show the right object.)

Edit: It was a lot of trouble for nothing... The problem is about the Variable View in XCode, which show my variable to "nil", whereas a log shows me a correct object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this...

```
{
    __weak IBOutlet UIProgressView *imageProcessingProgressView;
}
```

...and make the property strong.

Change your log message to...

```
NSLog(@"INIT: %@", self.imageProcessingProgressView);
```

...and see if you still have a problem.  If you do, then take another look at your storyboard connections.

Comment: Well... finally the error comes from the console: I see a nil adress for my imageProcessingProgressView, but the log gives a correct object... It seems that XCode has some trouble, it is not the first time I see this :/
Thanks, at least I know it's just the Variable View which is bugging.

Comment: However, in another function I try to set the value of the progress bar and it does not show up:
    [self.imageProcessingProgressView setProgress:[[notification object] floatValue]*100 animated:NO];
(the float value is correct because I log it.)
Is there any other function to call in order to show this change on screen? (If the answer is quick.)

Comment: Nevermind for this last question, I found the answer! Thank you for your help.

Comment: And (sorry for the multiple comments), note that the __weak stuff and all works fine (which is pretty great, because it's the code XCode wrote me automatically when I linked the object to the code !).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `NMLoadingViewController` is the class on your viewController

Comment: Yes the link between the view controller object and class is correct, because it stops to breakpoint set into the code of the class.

Comment: Well... See my answer to Phillip Mills, finally it worked but my Variable View is messed up... Thank you however.

Answer (score 0):

First try out the answer by @Eric because I do believe that is the real issue.

Also, make sure that you are actually using the interface builder to hook the controls back to the view controller. This is done by dragging a line from the control back to the property of the view controller.

Comment: As answered to Eric, I'm pretty sure the link for the view controller is ok; about the other point, I have dragged the progress view inside my view controller with the interface builder; then I have dragged a line from the progress view (with right-click/drag) to the .h file, which added the code written in my post.

Comment: Well... See my answer to Phillip Mills, finally it worked but my Variable View is messed up... Thank you however.